# How to feed CNN output as input series in a RNN (using Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have implemented a simple CNN using tensorflow. Up until now I used to put a fully connected layer of size 2 at the last convolutional layer to distinct between my 2 classes.
Now I want to feed that last convolutional layer to an RNN and then perform the classification.

The output of the last convolutional layer is called "cnn_output" and is a tensor of that form 
`<tf.Tensor 'Sigmoid_1:0' shape=(?, 168, 32) dtype=float32>`

before feeding it to the rnn I split it using this command: 
`input_series = tf.split(axis=2, num_or_size_splits= 32, value = cnn_output)`

the result of the split is 32 tensor of that type: 
`<tf.Tensor 'split:0' shape=(?, 168, 1) dtype=float32>`

the variables for the rnn are defined as below: 
`cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasesLSTMCell(32, state_is_tuple=True)`

`cell_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [168,32])`

`hidden_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [168,32])`

`init_state = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple( cell_state, hidden_state)`

to feed the output of the cnn to the rnn I use this command 
`states_series, current_state = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell, input_series, init_state)`

At this line I get the following error

`ValueError: linear is expecting 2D arguments: [TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(168), Dimension(1)]), TensorShape([Dimension(168), Dimension(32)])]`

To me it seems that there is something wrong with that first unknown dimension of the tensors but I am not sure how to deal with it.

I tried change the shape of the cell_state and hidden_state to [None,168,32] but didn't seem to help. 

I also tried to use the dynamic_rnn (not sure about the difference with static_rnn) but didn't work either

EDIT UPDATE:
I manage to run the code without error by reshaping the input_series of the rnn with this command:

```
input_series = [tf.reshape(ipt,[-1,168 ])for ipt in input_series]
```

which resulted in tensors like this

```
<tf.Tensor 'Reshape_21:0' shape=(?, 168) dtype=float32>
```

Although I am not sure yet if the rnn unit works properly. I will check it out and update

Answer (score 0):

I think your error comes from the fact that your placeholders are 2D and not 3D. You forgot to add a batch dimension.

Try to define them like this:

```
cell_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,168,32])
hidden_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,168,32])
```

(You might have to change the 32 to 1, given that your inputs have 1 channel each)

Comment: I already tried what you suggested, I mention that in my question. 
Tried to change the 32 to 1 but didn't work.
I think that somehow I need to transform my 3D tensors to 2D
which apparently is the dimension that "linear is expecting"